# Why Micronaut Test closed the MongoClient connection

Tags: micronaut, mongo-java-driver, micronaut-data, micronaut-test

I'm about testing using MongoDB. Instead of Micronaut Test Resources I'm using local hosted docker container for database (I prefer to see the result).
Many my tests depends on MongoDB but some throws that error:

```
17:34:09.134 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:26}] to localhost:27018
17:34:09.329 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-10] ERROR InternalError - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:166)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.startSession(MongoClientImpl.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.startSession(MongoClientImpl.java:132)
    at io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.DefaultMongoRepositoryOperations.withClientSession(DefaultMongoRepositoryOperations.java:753)
    at io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.DefaultMongoRepositoryOperations.findAll(DefaultMongoRepositoryOperations.java:253)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DefaultFindAllInterceptor.intercept(DefaultFindAllInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DefaultFindAllInterceptor.intercept(DefaultFindAllInterceptor.java:35)
    at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:143)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
```

What should I do that state will be open through all my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this via replace DefaultMongoClientFactory.
Difference between mine factory and Micronaut edition in the preDestroy action

at DefaultMongoClientFactory: 45

```java
@Bean(preDestroy = "close")
```

Workaround for tests:

```kotlin
package org.example.util.mongo

import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
import io.micronaut.configuration.mongo.core.DefaultMongoConfiguration
import io.micronaut.configuration.mongo.sync.DefaultMongoClientFactory
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.*
import jakarta.inject.Singleton


@Factory
@Requires(
    classes = [MongoClient::class],
    beans = [DefaultMongoConfiguration::class]
)
@Replaces(DefaultMongoClientFactory::class)
class MongoClientFactoryForTest {

    @Primary
    @Singleton
    @Replaces(MongoClient::class)
    fun mongoClient(settings: MongoClientSettings): MongoClient {

        return MongoClients.create(settings)
    }
}
```

```
@MicronautTest
@Requires(bean = MongoClientFactoryForTest::class)
abstract class IntegrationTestV1(body: FunSpec.() -> Unit = {}) : FunSpec(body) {
```

Micronaut-data team or Micronaut-test team, needs a comment :D